# How to require user to login on django, then redirect to original request

Tags: python, django, rest, http

I have a checkout view that I want to require the user to be logged in in order to access.

In order to do this, I am using the "login_required" decorator in front of the view:

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
```

And this works, however, the original request to "checkout" contains POST data that I want forwarded on. I thought using the "next" data attribute would work, but it doesn't retain any of the original POST data, just the base URL.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['usermail']
        password = request.POST['password']
        redirect = request.POST['next']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

How can I make sure when the user is redirected, the POST data of the original request is maintained?

Comment: I think most of the sites will ask you to fill the form again after logging in, but you can try saving the post in session and process it after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the Form data in `request.session` which is a `Dict`.  This is how `Django` stores cookies.

Then access this in your next view after the User is logged in.

So in the `Login Form`:

```
if user.is_active:
    auth_login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
else:
    request.session['form_data'] = request.POST
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Here are the Django Docs for `sessions`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/